# Can I use the object property's name as a string value in the object?

Tags: typescript

Can I use the object property's name as a string value in the object?
I mean I want to achieve this:

```
type MyObjectType = /* ... */

const myValidObject: MyObjectType = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
} // valid object of type MyObjectType

const myInvalidObject: MyObjectType = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'c'
} // invalid object of type MyObjectType, property b should have value 'b'
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
type MyObjectType = {
  [K: string]: `${K}`
}
```

Comment: There is no specific type in TS that works this way. You can write a generic type with a helper function to infer the generic type argument, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0vlow).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yup that's what i wanted, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *specific* type `MyObjectType` in TypeScript that would meet your needs. Instead, you can create a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type where the type parameter `K` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys in the object:

```
type MyObjectType<K extends PropertyKey> =
  { [P in K]: P }
```

But you probably don't want to have to write out `MyObjectType<"a" | "b">` yourself.  That means you will want a generic helper function to *infer* the type argument for you:

```
const myObjectType =
  <K extends PropertyKey>(o: MyObjectType<K>) => o;
```

Now instead of `const o: MyObjectType = {⋯}`, you write `const o = myObjectType({⋯})`.  It's about the same amount of work for you, but it gives you the desired behavior:

```
const myValidObject = myObjectType({
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
});
// const myValidObject: MyObjectType<"a" | "b">

const myInvalidObject = myObjectType({
  a: 'a',
  b: 'c' // error
  // Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
});
// const myInvalidObject: MyObjectType<"a" | "b">
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsAKuCAeA0lBAB7AQB2AJgM5QAKATgPaQOj4QgB8UAvALAAoKFADeUANp0oAS3JR8AXQBc9KAF8hQtE3LVgUALYIU6LDj5CRBIqQo16zVu05cAFE1VwkqDNkgEXACUfDxMANxagjp6BsYAagCGADYylD5mfEYmvuaQbqJWUImqAOSJpQA0RYhliKVC6kGRggD0rVAx+tlJqemmGF45Zv54AESJY1AAPlBjiGNcUV1xIACS5ABuKWkZGFnGe3kQBUUlUOVVNWVopVDtRAzMDEUPoxdjaGN3MrTkTAZEtRqDIAObkRKIZLQYBMKCgSAfBalAB0jWaQgeK2yG22fSOQyOo1wEyms3miyAA)